# Uno timer 2 set up

Tags: arduino-uno, timers

I am trying to use Timer2 in an Uno in fast PWM mode.  Can someone explain how to set up the TCCR2A & B registers?

Currently I have:

```
  TCCR2A |= _BV(WGM21) | _BV(WGM20);
  TCCR2B &= ~_BV(WGM22);

  TCCR2A = (TCCR2A | _BV(COM2A1)) & ~_BV(COM2A0);
  TCCR2A &= ~(_BV(COM2B1) | _BV(COM2B0));
  TCCR2B = (TCCR2B & ~(_BV(CS12) | _BV(CS11))) | _BV(CS10);
```

I would like to have the inverted value on TCCR2B, but I think it can be inverted using OCR2B ^= 255, correct?  This is to have a varying signal on Pin11 and its inverse on Pin3, the signal is generated by varying the OCR2B value.

Thanks

Comment: I realized a mistake, what I need to do is set up pins 11 and 3 (TCCR2 A & B?) to fast pwm mode.  Then I will set OCR2A to a value, and OCR2B to the value's inverse.  Should this work?

Comment: I also tried:   TCCR2A = (TCCR2A | _BV(COM2B1)) & ~_BV(COM2B0);
  TCCR2A &= ~(_BV(COM2A1) | _BV(COM2A0));
  TCCR2B = (TCCR2B & ~(_BV(CS12) | _BV(CS11))) | _BV(CS10);  But I'm still not getting output on pin 3.  Thanks.  Sorry for the excessive posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get two complementary PWM signals, you have to set *the
same* value to both output compare registers. This is necessary to have
the two signals in phase. You also have to configure one PWM in
non-inverting mode and the other in inverting mode. For example:

```c++
TCCR2A = _BV(COM2A1)  // non-inverting PWM on OC2A
       | _BV(COM2B0)  // PWM on OC2B:
       | _BV(COM2B1)  //    inverting mode
       | _BV(WGM20)   // fast PWM
       | _BV(WGM21);  // ditto
TCCR2B = _BV(CS10);   // clock at F_CPU / 1
OCR2A  = 84;          // duty cycle ~ 1/3
OCR2B  = 84;          // same signal, complemented
```

Checked on the scope: when pin 3 goes high pin 11 goes low and
vice-versa.

Comment: Thank you.  What I need is both PWM signals in non-inverting mode.  Then I need to invert the duty cycle OCR2B w.r.t. OCR2A.  So as OCR2A increases, OCR2B will decrease the same.  The actual PWM signals are to be in-phase, but complementary duty cycle.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks Edgar, I was able to sort through the 328p datasheet and get the registers figured out.  First time I have worked with registers and bit values and bit math so it took me some time to understand this but it works really well now.  Thanks again.